# Return only the newest rows from a BigQuery table with a duplicate items

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with many duplicate items – Many rows with the same `id`, perhaps with the only difference being a `requested_at` column.

I'd like to do a `select *` from the table, but only return one row with the same `id` – the most recently requested.

I've looked into `group by id` but then I need to do an aggregate for each column. This is easy with `requested_at` – `max(requested_at) as requested_at` – but the others are tough.

How do I make sure I get the value for `title`, etc that corresponds to that most recently updated row?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest a similar form that avoids a sort in the window function:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT
          *,
          MAX(<timestamp_column>)
              OVER (PARTITION BY <id_column>)
              AS max_timestamp,
      FROM <table>
    )
    WHERE <timestamp_column> = max_timestamp
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT
          *,
          ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER (
                  PARTITION BY <id_column>
                  ORDER BY <timestamp column> DESC)
              row_number,
      FROM <table>
    )
    WHERE row_number = 1
```

Note it will add a `row_number` column, which you might not want. To fix this, you can select individual columns by name in the outer select statement.

In your case, it sounds like the `requested_at` column is the one you want to use in the `ORDER BY`.

And, you will also want to use allow_large_results, set a destination table, and specify no flattening of results (if you have a schema with repeated fields).